# C++ convert a union into an integer

Tags: c++, serialization, unions

I have 2 type aliases:

```cpp
struct A { uint64_t i; };
struct B { uint64_t j; };
```

`A` and `B` are not the same type, and are not `uint64_t` primarily for readability reasons. They represent IDs of program resources that are inherently different (e.g. `A` represents the ID of an image, and `B` represents the ID of a raw buffer).

For most of the program's lifetime, they are kept separate and do their own thing, however at one point they need to be serialized. To prevent writing identical logic for both, and to prevent using templates (long story), I made a union:

```cpp
union ResourceHandle {
    A a;
    B b;
}
```

Say I have this struct:

```cpp
struct MetaData
{
    ResourceHandle handle;
    /* other data */
}
```

I want to write `void Serialize(const MetaData& data);`

I know that the handle is a `uint64_t`, so I just want to cast the union into this type by adding:

```cpp
union ResourceHandle
{
    A a;
    B b;
        
    operator uint64_t() const { return a; }
};
```

I suspect this is undefined behaviour, but I think it will generally work in most systems. Is there a way I can reliably cast from the `union` into a `uint64_t` without using additional memory to check which of the two is actually stored?

Comment: In general I tend to stay to stay away from unions so I'm not sure if this is applicable, but it sounds like you may find what you need by reading about "Common Initial Sequence".

Comment: If you write a templated serialize function, you won’t have to worry about the underlying type

Comment: @Makogan First off, you would have to use `return a.i;` instead. But, like you said, this would be UB if `b` is the active field instead of `a`. If you *know* the `union` will always contain a value, you just don't know which one, I would probably use `return *reinterpret_cast<const uint64_t*>(this);` instead.

Comment: You could use a `std::variant<A, B>` in place of a union, but that would implicitly use the "additional memory" you seem to want to avoid.

Comment: It seems that either the tempalte or the reinterpretation are the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a base class e.g.: struct ID { uint64_t id; };
and make A and B a derived class of ID.
Finally you can serialize the base class.